# What Enchantment wizard spells would synergize well with a Beast Master ranger's animal companion?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, multi-classing, ranger, animal-companions

I'm just getting into my first character, and planning on eventually multiclassing Beast Master ranger and Enchantment wizard.

What enchantment wizard spells would synergize well with a Beast Master's animal companion?

I realize I may have to earn a great deal of experience before this becomes available, but would there be anything worth working towards, or should I look through some other subclasses?

Comment: What level is your character now, and how far do you think this campaign will go?  5th, 11th, 15th? 20th?  Also, what ranger spells have you considered for use with your companion, if any?  It would be useful to explain why you feel the need to multiclass.  Welcome to RPG.SE.  Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to see how this Q&A site is different from a discussion forum.

Comment: You might want to ask a question about combining two specific features or spells of Ranger and Wizard, and ask what the benefits or mechanical consequences would be of the combination.